# Unity3d: access from plugin android file aar to external image

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, npm, launch-screen

It is possible in Unity from the android aar file plugin to access an image from outside this arr file?

I'm making an npm package that contains the Android launch screen setup. and in the resources there is a link to the picture in style.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splashscreen</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The picture is in folder "res/drawable" of "aar" file. When installing npm the package int Unity3d, this file must be replaced somehow, or a link to the file must be written here from outside